# Return only sum of values based on a key condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following list

```
a = [(1:0.4), (6:0.15), (6:0.15), (7:0.1)]
```

And want to return only the sum of values where the key equals a certain value. E.g. the sum of values where the key equals 6 would be 0.3. I thought the below would work:

```
= sum(values for key, values in a.items() if key == 6)
```

Any suggestions appreciated on what the correct syntax is.

Comment: what is the type of `6:0.15` ? string?

Comment: That is not a list you could actually have.

Comment: is it `a = [{1:0.4},{6:0.15},...]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
a = [[1,0.4], [6,0.15], [6,0.15], [7,0.1]]

sumvalue = 0
for b in a:
    if b[0] == 6:
        sumvalue += b[1]
```

In any case, the list you are presenting in your question cannot exist.

Also if something does not work, it is usually better to take smaller steps.

**EDIT:** Depending on how your data structure will look like eventually, the answer above is probably better.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just getting to grips with python data structures.

Comment: hmmmm ... this will just give you a sum where the key is 6 ... Im not entirely sure thats what OP was asking for (although its certainly a step in the right direction)

Comment: That's how I understood the question at least.

Answer (score 2):

ill assume that you actually have a list of dicts, and not whatever weird datastructure that is in your original question that does not exist in python

```
a = [{1:0.4}, {6:0.15}, {6:0.15}, {7:0.1}]

from collections import defaultdict
sums = defaultdict(int)

for data_dict in a:
    for k,v in data_dict.items():
        sums[k] += v

print sums
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Just getting to grips with python data structures.

Answer (score 0):

`a = [(1:0.4), (6:0.15), (6:0.15), (7:0.1)]` is illegal python expression.

you may mean `a = [{1:0.4}, {6:0.15}, {6:0.15}, {7:0.1}]`.

If so, then `sum([item[6] for item in a if list(item.keys())==[6]])`